# Visual Studio 'Rebuild Solution' Errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, solution, rebuild

I have a web project that relies on two separately compiled projects and all three are in the same solution. One day out of the blue, I hit Rebuild Solution and I got a whole list of errors that I'd never received before. Apparently the Rebuild would delete the dependent DLLs and then be unable to build the web project DLL because it couldn't find the dependent DLLs. Now I have another web project that's set up identically and this has never happened and on both projects the dependencies are set up correctly. If I try using just Build Solution, it works just fine. Only Rebuild Solution causes the errors to come up and it only does it on one of my projects and it never used to do it. I know of no changes between the time Rebuild worked and the time it didn't. I just opened it up one day and it decided to no longer work. I'm at a total loss here so I was hoping someone may have experienced this issue before and could give me some insight. Thanks.

Comment: When you rebuild or clean, Visual Studio will remove stuff from bin. If it removes things that surprise you, you may end up with a missing reference. Or it is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Setup  dependencies:

-Right click the solution.

-Select Properties.

-Select Project Dependencies.

-Select your DLL.

[image]

Comment: That's what I did originally. Doesn't work. I've set it up the exact same way on my other project and it works just fine. It's very weird. I even recreated the entire project. Same result.

Comment: One of your source files might have a bogus date that is confusing things.   Check the dates on them to make sure they aren't 10 years in the future or past.  Check for pre-build and post-build scripts that might be messing you up.